# Can I cause referring to ellipsis (3 dots - Unicode 8230) as 3 seperated dots (Unicode 46 - '.' * 3) (c#)?

Tags: c#, html

I want to count how many dots ('.') I have in an Hebrew file text.
The problem is that sometimes I have in my text the sequence '...' (3 dots).
I want this sequence to be referred as 3 separated dots, but, sometimes my c# code 'understands' them as 3 separated dots ('.'  *  3) and sometimes - as a one '...' sequence (Unicode 8230 - '...'). 
why it is not consistency? and how I can always identify them as 3 dots?

//part of the code:

```
foreach (char c in line)   //line is "שלום ... . . . ..."
{
    if (c == letter)   //letter is '.'
      counter++;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have left out the picture, though I question why you would use a picture instead of pasting some of the text and formatting it as code (**Ctrl-K**)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just have a lot of inconsistently-spelled ellipses (plural of ellipsis) in your file …

1. `...`, three ordinary ASCII characters
2. `…`, one Unicode character